# Grunt - Run Grunt Task During another Grunt Task

Tags: gruntjs

I am attempting to run another grunt task in the middle of a loop that is part of another task. Currently the below code finishes the "publishComponents" task then runs the "artifactory" task. The reason I am doing this is, I have a list of components that need to be published and I don't to have to repeat the same publish task with different names, rather read from a file.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
    grunt.registerTask('publishComponents', 'do some stuff.', function() {
    var componentList = grunt.file.readJSON('./componentList.json');
    for (var i = 0; i < componentList.components.length; i++) {
        componentName = componentList.components[i]["name"];
        //Set File Location in Task
        fileLocation = "**/"+ componentName + "/**";
        grunt.config.set('artifactory.component.files.0.src.0', fileLocation);

        //Set Publish Name for Artifactory
        publishName = 'component:' + componentName + '-component:zip';
        grunt.config.set('artifactory.component.options.publish.0.id', publishName);

        //Set Build Name for Artifactory
        buildName = 'build.name=' + componentName + '-1.0';
        grunt.config.set('artifactory.component.options.parameters.0', buildName);
        grunt.task.run('artifactory:component:publish');
    }
});
```